# Firebase hosting does not upload 100% when deploying

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I was deploying some updates for my web app, but found out that not all files were updated after the deployment. Some functions broke because of this and I found out that when deploying, it didn't upload the full 100%. I think this is why it does not update every file. Somebody knows how to fix this? Since the new update it makes a 'functions' folder, which is around 12-20mb. I don't need functions, so do you have to have this per se?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: If you don't want to include functions on deploy you can use `firebase deploy --only hosting,database,storage`.

Comment: The Firebase tools write a log file when you run `firebase deploy`. Is there anything about problems in that file?

Comment: Thanks Pieter. @FrankvanPuffelen, do you mean the .firebaserc file? The weird thing is, when I go to <myApp>.firebaseapp.com, the changes are correct and updated. I am aware of a cache problem, but I've tried it on multiple devices and that shows the same error (also after hard refresh etc)

Comment: I'm having the same issue (67% for me), using latest version of firebase tools. It's causing some aspects of the website to be updated and some not, and so it's extremely problematic. @FrankvanPuffelen do you have any ideas on how to get around this? Thanks

Comment: I'm still having this issue as well

Comment: Edit: Issue fixed by new firebase-tools update

Answer (score 0):

If your files are in the format of .js , .ejs or other such formats, just put them in functions folder. If they are in .html , .txt ,.xml etc, drop them in public folder.